# VB.net fastest way to check if a string contains 1 of many strings

Tags: vb.net, string

OK, so i want to check if a large string contains one (any) of many other strings within an array.

I can loop through that array and perform 'if largestring.contains(arrayitem) do something then exit for' but i feel this is probably inefficient especially if the array of strings is very large.

Plus the performance will vary depending on the position in the array of the found string
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you care about case/culture sensitivity? And is this a String[] or an ArrayList or a List<String> or some other "array" container?

Comment: I do not care about case. Its a straight forward array containing string values, eg array(0) = 'cat' array(1) = 'dog'.

Comment: If the data is very large (and potentially get a lot bigger) your a probably better off putting it in a database and using SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best Approach I think is to use regular expressions

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim arrayitems As New Regex(arrayitem(0) & "|" & arrayitem(1) & "|"  & arrayitem(2))

If arrayitems.IsMatch(largestring) Then 
  'Exists
  '...
End If
```

Another Alternative is to use IndexOf which (in theory) is marginally faster than Contains

```
Dim str As String = "Hello World."

' Does the string contain "World"?
If (str.IndexOf("World") <> -1) Then
  Console.Write("string contains 'World'")
Else
  Console.Write("string does not contain 'World'")
End If
```

Comment: I tested regex and it's slower than the loop approach. And I doubt IndexOf performance will be much better than Contains, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Looks like i'll stick with my method then, though i will try substituting Contains for IndexOf

Answer (score 1):

Dim result As String() = Array.FindAll(arr, Function(s) s.Contains("whatever"))

Comment: Unless im mistaken, this searches within the array for a single value, i want to search within a single string to see if it contains any one of multiple values (contained in an array).I do not even need to return the found string, just know that it contains at least one of them.

Comment: Oh I see... yeah that is a little more complicated, but this might be a start.